# maximally exclusive paths in a DAG

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, dag

Suppose we have a DAG $G$ with one source node $s$, ie. it has a path to every node, and target node $t$ which every node has a path to it. For a pair of paths from $s$ to $t$ we can define a distance function $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ as:
$$d(P_1,P_2) = |(P_1 - P_2) \cup (P_2 - P_1)|$$
We want to find  the maximum value of this function computed all possible paths between $s$ and $t$: 
$$D = \max_{P_1,P_2} \big\{ d(P_1,P_2)\big\}$$

You can think of this measure as a distance between two paths and therefore the problem can be thought of finding the "diameter" of a graph that its vertices are paths on $G$ and its edges' weights are determined by this formula.

Because $G$ is a DAG the number of paths between $s$ and $t$ is finite and therefore the quantity is well defined.

I have tried to find an upper bound for $D$ in a linear time with respect to nodes and edges of the graph. 
Suppose we take a random path $P_r$. We try to find the path that is maximally different from $P_r$. If we find the most distant path from this path, namely $P_s$ diameter cannot be bigger than $2 d(P_r,P_s)$, that is: 
$$D \le 2 d(P_r, P_s)$$
This can be done by setting the weight of the edges on $P_r$ to zero and then finding the maximum distance between $s$ and $t$ on the new graph. This can be done in linear time. But I haven't figured a way on how to choose the $P_r$ or how to directly compute $D$

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: You might want to check out if you can model the problem as one of finding maximal flows.

Comment: @Raphael I've put down my thoughts that go quite some way in the direction of solving the problem, I believe, if I knew the solution I wouldn't be asking the question in the first place. Which solutions involving max-flow do you know of that are sort of similar?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem lists both the edge- and vertex-disjoint paths problem as a max flow problem.